# Null Layout default JFrame dimension?

Tags: java, jframe

I have made a JForm in netbeans and have set the current layout to Null Layout, once I run the program however the default dimensions of the JFrame is so small as opposed to Free Design Layout. Again, i'm using netbean's JForm so I don't think i can specifically go in and change the dimensions, just as to what is defaulted with the Null layout.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the edit on the image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `frame.pack()` before making the frame visible (or to simplify, you can use it before the line `frame.setVisible(true)`).

This will resize your JFrame to fit the size of its contents.

Comment: I'm not too sure where i would put this in my code, as JForm generates quite a bit of generic code. In this puush it looks like it is calling the pack() method though. http://puu.sh/lyFj4/d86aec74a2.png

Comment: you should use layout manager... thats whats causing the problem. Is there a reason you set layout to null? Its always better to use a layout manager, because even while providing easier layout codes they help keep the proportion of elements while resizing frame. And you also dont have any control over how elements render on screen without layout manager (which is bad, Very bad). So unless you have a strong reason, you should definitely use layout manager.

Comment: so i could use a JLabel as a Background img of my GUI, thats the only reason i set it to null. When i set it to Free Design Layout, there is an issue where some JFrame components won't show up.

Comment: Thats not the correct way. There's a special java class for that purpose. Check out BufferedImage Class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html
Do things the cleaner way. So you will reduce the potential errors and management problems.

Comment: I only did it this way as all the top google hits were done via this method, i didn't personally like it. Thank you for the point in the right direction!